# Is there a hint text property in wxWidgets codeblocks?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, wxwidgets

I wanted to use hint text property for my checkbox but there is no option like in visual basic.
How can I do this? Is there an alternative?

Comment: do you want to use it inside C::B or in the wxWidgets application? Please clarify?

Comment: `MyControl->SetToolTip(wxString("This is a hint"));`